# Make Div Empty and Re Fill It cause my page Flash in All Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

i have div like This :

```
 <div id="PartialOnPortFolioGrid" >

</div>
```

and in my Java Script File i use this code to remove and rebind the data like This:

```
 $("#PartialOnPortFolioGrid").empty();
 $("#PartialOnPortFolioGrid").html(datasearch);
```

And When im Running it, it cause my page kind of flash in other words all elements hide and show 
so how can i fix it ?
by the way in my div i have a Kendo Grid

Comment: Did you try to remove the first line, it's not really needed.

Comment: yeah `.empty()` is not required if you are using `.html()`. `.html()` overwrites everything available in that elem.

Comment: i remove the empty() line thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You could either use effects/animation to make the transition slow to see if it makes things smoother or not.

Or

you can set the visibility of the div to hidden then load the html content and then set visibility again to visible. That might solve the issue.

Comment: i use visibility hidden but it doesn't work also i use slide down and again i have flash in my page

Comment: @Shahram Well, in that case i will have to look at the page contents so that can understand what all things are there on page.